# jQuery magicLine vertical sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've used jQuery MagicLine as a vertical sliding. I want it to be like this, when I click the menus, the line will be staying at that menu item, and not go back to the first one as usual.And also whenever a click on the down arrow of the page, magicline should work accordingly. Please advise. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  magicline();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
     $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
       if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
       && location.hostname == this.hostname
       && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
         var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
         var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
          if ($target) {
            var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
   
     <!----- JQUERY CLICK FUNCTION REMOVE AND ADD CLASS "ACTIVE" + SCROLL TO THE #DIV--->   
            $(this).click(function() {
      $("#nav_menu li a").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass('active');
              $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
              return false;
            });
         }
       }
     });
   
   
   });


function magicline() {
  var $el, topPos, newHeight,
    $mainNav = $("#nav_menu");
  //$("#magic_line").remove();
  $mainNav.append("<li id='magic_line'></li>");
  var $magicLine = $("#magic_line");

  $magicLine
    .height($(".current_page_item").height())
    .css("top", $(".current_page_item a").position().top)
    .data("origTop", $magicLine.position().top)
    .data("origHeight", $magicLine.height());

  $("#nav_menu li").find("a").hover(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    topPos = $el.position().top;
    newHeight = $el.parent().height();
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
      top: topPos,
      height: newHeight
    });
  }, function() {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
      top: $magicLine.data("origTop"),
      height: $magicLine.data("origHeight")
    });
  });
}

$('#nav_menu li a').bind('click', function() {
  $('#nav_menu li').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('current_page_item');
  });
  $(this).parent().addClass('current_page_item');
  magicline();
});
```

```css
nav#nav_wrap {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5000;
  top: 40vh;
  right: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: url(images/navbg.png) no-repeat left;
}
li{ list-style: none; }
nav#nav_wrap ul {
  width: 115px;
}
nav#nav_wrap ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
nav#nav_wrap ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}
nav#nav_wrap ul li a.dot:hover,
nav#nav_wrap ul li a.dot:active {
  background: #52C6C0;
}
nav#nav_wrap .dot.active {
  background: #52C6C0;
}
nav#nav_wrap .dot {
  background: #005F59;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.menu_title {
  margin-left: 22px;
}
#magic_line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 142px;
  background: url(images/marker.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav_wrap" class="nav-wrap">
  <ul class="group navigation" id="nav_menu">
    <li class="current_page_item">
      <a href="#home" class="dot active">
        <div class="menu_title">Home</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#about" class="dot">
        <div class="menu_title">About</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#services" class="dot">
        <div class="menu_title">Services</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#portfolio" class="dot">
        <div class="menu_title">Media</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contact" class="dot">
        <div class="menu_title">Contact</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks for any help.

**Edit :** 
Here is a working JSFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/9cg5bqxw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Impossible to get 50 rep (stuck on 49 for days now haha), so this isn't an answer yet, but a comment.*

Please elaborate what you are trying to do, this isn't clear to my and neither the snippet or the JS Fiddle are clear to what you are asking.

Do you have a working example from someone because :

> when I click the menus, the line will be staying at that menu item,
>   and not go back to the first one as usual.And also whenever a click on
>   the down arrow of the page, magicline should work accordingly.

Isn't really a clear explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

**Edit :**
I think this is what you are looking for : http://jsfiddle.net/xfba1403/8/

*What went wrong :*

A couple of things went wrong :

- You forgot to add the "on hover" function :

  `$("#nav_menu li a").hover(function() {
              $el = $(this);
              topPos = $el.position().top;
              newHeight = $el.parent().height();
              $magicLine.stop().animate({
                  top: topPos,
                  height: newHeight
              });
          }, function() {
              $magicLine.stop().animate({
                  top: $magicLine.data("origTop"),
                  height: $magicLine.data("origHeight")
              });

          });`
- The image you are using, maybe works on your pc but doesnt on jsfiddle so i changed it to a color :

  `#magic_line {
      position: absolute;
      color: black;
      top: 5px;
      left: 0;
      width: 5px;
      background-color: #fe4902;
  }`

*What I edited because of duplicate / weird use: *

- You used `$(document).ready(function(){ // code });` twice for some reason.

*Tip*

I Advice you to start using Bootstrap it is getting the most commonly used Library for making standard websites, after you build a great Alpha you can easily edit it :)

Reference : http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: I want similar working but it is to be vertical. http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/vtuKH/1/

Comment: Before hand, I would advise you to edit your answer, remove all the unnecessary code and add the js fiddle. Please be sure to still have some code in your question which is relevant to the question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xfba1403/6/  || This is my code. I have placed an image on the left(for the magic line) of the navigation menu.Its a vertical scroller. but its not showing here. When you click on the squares, the magic line should go to the menu item and stay there.

Comment: it worked here. But its not working in my website. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Jp Houten... Your answer is correct. But this too works for me. Thanks.

```js
function magicline() {
      var $el, topPos, newHeight;
      $mainNav = $("#nav_menu");
      
      $mainNav.append("<li id='magic_line'></li>");
      var $magicLine = $("#magic_line");
     var isClicked = false;  // to show whether menu is clicked or not
     
     $magicLine.height($(".current_page_item").height())
      .css("top", $(".current_page_item a").position().top)
      .data("origTop", $magicLine.position().top)
      .data("origHeight", $magicLine.height());
     
     $("#nav_menu li").find("a").hover(function () {
      $el = $(this);
      topPos = $el.position().top;
      newHeight = $el.parent().height();
      
      $magicLine.stop().animate({
       top: topPos,
       height: newHeight
      });
     }, function () {
      if(!isClicked){         // if no item is clicked, take line to old position
       $magicLine.stop().animate({
        top: $magicLine.data("origTop"),
        height: $magicLine.data("origHeight")
       });
      }else{                 // else, just keep it there  
       isClicked = false;
       return false;
      }
     }).click(function(e){   // added click listener 
      isClicked = true;       // flag is set to indicate menu item is clicked.
      $magicLine.css({
       top: topPos,
       height: newHeight
      });                             
     });
      
   }
```

Comment: I have an arrow which on clicking moves to next page. I want this magic line navigation to be worked along with this arrow click. The down arrow is placed at the bottom of each section. Welcomes any help. Thanks

Comment: What you can check is in which section (#) you are, and depending on that switching to the right <li>

Comment: I found till this. I couldn't find the right <a> element with the same id. $('.arrow-down').click(function() {
         href = $(this).attr('href');
      alert(href);  
     }); Please help me.

Comment: You should give each button with a unique behaviour a unique ID.
Btw. $('.arrow-down') calls a class not a ID, an id would be called like $('#arrow-down')